# What parameters do I provide to the fit function of the FeatureAgglomeration in sklearn for precomputed distances?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I want to use FeatureAgglomeration in SKLearn with a number of data points (each defined by multiple features) and a pre-defined affinity (or distance) matrix.

I've used AgglomerativeClustering, with affinity set to precomputed, and in the fit function I've provided a matrix with my precomputed distances to much success.

With FeatureAgglomeration I understand that I have to provide both the features of each data point and the precomputed distance, but I can't work out what input is meant to be provided to the fit function (fit(X, y=none)) and it doesn't appear to be documented (specifically the case when you are using pre-computed).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and the documentation is not helpful here. However, I figured out that `fit()` expects a distance matrix and `transform()` the feature matrix to be reduced in dimensionality. This becomes clear when reading the source code of `FeatureAgglomeration`, particularly the following two parts

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/cluster/_agglomerative.py#L1237

and

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b611bf873bd5836748647221480071a87/sklearn/cluster/_feature_agglomeration.py#L18

Hope this helps.